# Waiting for object creation or accessing it immediately if it already exists

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, rx-java

I've faced the following problem today: we have a class `Foo` which has an instance of `Bar` inside of it. A method `initBar()` is called at some point during a lifecycle of class (which is very asynchronous, lots of RxJava) and it does `bar = new Bar()`

Now, the problem is that I want to access `bar` inside of some other method `doStuff()`, which is not guaranteed to be called after the `initBar()`, so the `bar` can either still be `null` or already exist.

If `bar` already exists I want to run a function `analyze(bar)` synchronously right away, if it's still `null` - I want to schedule it to run once `bar` is set (as a part of `initBar()` call).

**Bonus questions**: how to specify on which thread `analyze(bar)` should be executed; what if multiple methods want to access `bar`; how to safely cancel these.

Now, I know how to implement this using RxJava: add extra `PublishSubject<Bar> subject` and subscribe to it while calling `.repeat()` to get the value if it was already set, and then from `initBar()` do `subject.onNext(bar)`. That's easy. It even covers the case of accessing it from multiple places and specifying a thread to run the code on.

But I feel like I'm reinventing a wheel here - there probably is a solution out there for this type of problems, when you want to access an object without worrying on whether it's already set or not. Should it be considered *Promise* and be done with `CompletableFuture` or [JDeferred](http://jdeferred.org/)? Or is there some nice `RxJava` recipe for this already? There's gotta be something clean and easy ...

Here's full code of `Foo` for reference:

```
class Foo {
    Bar bar;

    void initBar() { bar = new Bar(); }

    void doStuff() {
         //This is the missing piece
         doWhenBar(bar -> analyze(bar));
    }

    void lifecycle1() {
        Observable.create(..)
            ...
            .doOnNext(this::initBar())
            ...
    }

    void lifecycle2() {
        Observable.create(..)
            ...
            .subscribe(this::doStuff())
    }

    //More methods where lifecycle1() and lifecycle2() can be called in random order
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `bar` is only created once, use a `SingleSubject` and now you can react to `Bar` being created:

```java
class Foo {
    final SingleSubject<Bar> bar = SingleSubject.create();

    void initBar() { bar.onSuccess(new Bar()); }

    Single<Bar> doStuff() {
         //This is the missing piece
         return bar.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
         .doOnSuccess(b -> analyze(b));
    }

    void lifecycle1() {
        Observable.create(..)
        ...
        .doOnNext(this::initBar())
        ...
    }

    void lifecycle2() {
        Observable.create(..)
        ...
        .concatMapSingle(this::doStuff)
        .subscribe(...)
    }

// More methods where lifecycle1() and lifecycle2()
// can be called in random order
...
}
```